# Checking an OutputStream for broken pipe

Tags: java

```java
void sendMessage(String message, OutputStream os) {
    try {
        ExternalLibrary.sendMessage(message, os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have the above bit of code that uses an external method to send a message through an output stream. If there's an IO exception (e.g. a broken pipe), that method will perform some logging and throw than IOException. I want to prevent the logging from happening if there's a broken pipe. The logging performed by the method is vague and difficult to look through, so I only want to call it if I can be reasonably sure the pipe isn't broken. Something like:

```java
void sendMessage(String message, OutputStream os) {
    if (!os.isClosed()) {
        try {
            ExternalLibrary.sendMessage(message, os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        logger.error("Broken pipe");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean PipedOutputStream? What makes you think it is a Pipe?

Comment: I do not. The OutputStream is itself a generic OutputStream, but it sends data over the network. It may be passed in a PipedOutputStream, but I don't necessarily have control over that.

Comment: Are you sure that the moment you call sendMessage the OutputStream provide all required informations? I mean you can not look into the future and tell that the OutputStream is not broken.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The method does nothing more with the output stream than try to send data through. I need to check to see if there would be a broken pipe exception prior to calling ExternalLibrary.sendMessage().

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a MultiThreaded environment you can never be sure if a asynchrouius task invalidate the OutputStream throu a different Thread.

A simplified example:

You start the sending of the message. Right after sending the message your PC is running out of RAM, the OutputStream breaks because it can not allocate more RAM - voila your stream is broken. This is happening after the calling of the function but before the leave of the function.

Comment: I'm not overly worried about that. Generally speaking, this method is only called as the result of an exception (i.e. broken pipe).

Answer (score 0):

The concept of "broken" is unknown to a OutputStream! Also a Pipe is a different kind of design. You mean Streams.

Only the method `write(*)` is able to produce a `IOException` what can be used to express a broken pipe.

Unfortunately the method `write(*)` is called inside `ExternalLibrary.sendMessage(message, os);`.

That is too late for your task to

> call it if I can be reasonably sure the pipe isn't broken